# Div behave as Table

Tags: css

```
    <div>
    <label>VERTICAL_NAMES</label>
    <input type="text" name="VERTICAL_NAME" id="VERTICAL_NAME"  />
    <label>VERTICAL_NAMES</label>
    <input type="hidden" name="VERTICAL_NAME" id="VERTICAL_CODE" />
    </div>

o/p :
    VERTICAL_ID          Textbox 
      VERTICAL_NAME      Textbox

I can not able to bring this 

      VERTICAL_ID          Textbox 
      VERTICAL_NAME        Textbox
```

how we can bring above o/p using css

Comment: y u want to do this in div???... use table

Comment: @jimy - that is not tabular data - you would be wrong to do this with a table.

Comment: @easwee using table for a form is not wrong.....

Comment: @jimy Semanticaly it is wrong. You have form, fieldset elements - use those to style the form elements, compensate missing elements with a div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like...

```
label {
    float: left;  
    clear: left;
    width: 200px;
}

input {
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
}
```

would do it (assuming you fix up your html first!)

Sample [here](http://jsfiddle.net/shooter/hHjj5/).

Answer (score 0):

You would want to do something along the lines of this http://jsfiddle.net/8XrhD/, however this code will effect all your `label` and `input` controls on the page.

Answer (score 0):

```
label { float: left; width: x; }
input { margin-left: x; }
div { margin-bottom: .4em; }
```

Answer (score -1):

css:

```
div {
  clear: both;
}

label {
  float: left;
  width: 10em;
}
```

Comment: This would not work as both labels would float to the left and the textbox's would sit to the right

Comment: Ah, my bad - misread the source. Adding a clear: left; to the label would fix it.